# Different file indirection at every watch execution

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

I'm trying to collect some data at every second to different file(preferably timed name file). I'm trying to use watch command but it's not behaving as per expectation.

```
watch -p -n 1 "curl -s  http://127.0.0.1:9273/metrics > `date +'%H-%M-%S'`.txt"
```

Only 1 file is created and data is being directed to it. I was expecting it to write to different files. I'm not looking to alternative methods. Can it be modified to achieve said task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

quote it with **single quote**
or wrap the command line passed to watch ,  with bash -c
pay attention to the quotes i used,  they can not be swapped
both following command works for one second per file

```
watch -p -n 1 'curl -s  http://127.0.0.1:9273/metrics > `date +'%H-%M-%S'`.txt'

watch -p -n 1 'bash -c "curl -s  http://127.0.0.1:9273/metrics > `date +'%H-%M-%S'`.txt"'
```